# How to edit a Wordpress theme and make it easy to update?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can you start making changes inside a WP theme and then keep track of them for future them updates ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some sort of version control software like subversion to track updates. Also in terms of just "hacking", it is all based in PHP so you can just drop into your theme and make changes as needed to any of the files as they pertain to what you want to do. For example in order to make any sort of changes to the header, typically you would edit the header.php file.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be a version control system like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 0):

My experience has shown that it is best to go with a very well developed and customizable theme (occasionally paid) that allows you to make the majority of changes within the theme's settings rather than hard coding them. When the theme is updated by the author, while not impossible, I find it is rare they've butchered something from a previous version. If they did, they'll often offer not only a reason but a possible work-around.

Another think would be to have a testing environment where you can try out new releases of a theme without risking harm to your live site. Just google 'wordpress testing environment' and that should point you in the right direction. For the record, I run XAMPP on a spare windows pc for this process.

Last bit of advice: if you do make any changes to your theme, back the theme files up regularly. In the event something does go haywire, you wont have to design the site from scratch.